# Clear only 1 row of DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datagridview

Is there any possible way to clear only 1 row in DataGridView in c#?
cause when embedding this code

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

It clears all items in my datagrid. I only want one item row to be cleared when triggered by a button.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to remove the current row on the dgv.

```
  YourDGVName.Rows.RemoveAt(YourDGVName.CurrentRow.Index);
```

You can also take the selected rows or a specific row number each time.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove a row like this if you already have the row:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
```

or, you can remove the selected row like this:

```
var rowToRemove = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex];
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
```

or, like this:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
```

or, if you want to clear all selected rows:

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

ideally though, you would want to bind to a datasource (usually through a ViewModel), and then remove the selected datum from the source.

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo the second implementation will clear it by index. Also, see update

Comment: Encountered error in Rows

 "Non ivocable member 'DataGridView.Rows' cannot be used like a method "
-------------------------------------
Encountered error in Item

DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo see update, my mistake, was typing too fast.